# After Mysql Migration Woocomerce Category is not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I move my database from **Mysql 5.7** to **Mysql 8** in a cluster. I don't know why, but the woocommerce category gets strange.
In the database, i have all information about the category **(wp_terms)**, on backend the count and pagination are correct, but the categories are not showing on the list table and the URL not exits on the frontend.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAot9.png)

Answer (score -1):

After 15h trying and searching for a solution, i  found. The problem was on **MYSQL 8** database config

On **MYSQL 5.7** the SQL mode has included the mode ***ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY*** that protects a user by rejecting *non-deterministic-result* queries which contain **GROUP BY** or aggregate functions. On the new MYSQL version, this mode was removed.
I discovered when i enabled the Wordpress debug and got this error::

```
Error Code: 3065. Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'wp_termmeta.meta_value' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT
```

The final solution has added this config below on MYSQL SQL mode config:

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

After doing this, the cluster worked correctly.